# Weird output after inserting std::ends

Tags: c++

If I write `cout << "Hi!" << ends << "1234";`, the `1` will disappear after a while. From C++ reference, I know that `std::ends` **inserts a null character into the stream**. But when does this insertion happen?

The full code is

```
    #include <iostream>

    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        std::cout << "Hi!" << std::ends << "1234";
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Running the program shows [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ACls.png)
,after maybe 0.5 second, it becomes [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECVbF.png).

Comment: I believe the effect of writing the NUL character to standard output is terminal-specific.

Comment: @Bathsheba I posted two pictures that show the behavior.

Comment: @molbdnilo That may be the reason. I use the VS2013 command line.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the language itself is concerned, all `cout << ends` does is write `\0` to the stream. It does *not* close the stream or cause things to be unexpectedly re-ordered. For the avoidance of any doubt, in your case, the language guarantees that `"Hi!"` will be be buffered *before* `\0` and that is buffered *before* `"1234"`.

My understanding is that a terminal *ought* to silently ignore `\0`. (It should regard it as an NOP, i.e. no-operation, instruction), but some terminals interpret it, in error, as a space.

That appears to be happening in your case.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just tried compiling using gcc but not vs2013 cl. And this problem did not happen again.